# Where i can get a compatible NCreport library for Qt 5.1.0 or Qt 5.1.1

Tags: c++, qt, printing, reporting, qmake

i have a problem with ncreport  library

i'm using Qt 4.8.5 and minGW compiler

```
C:\test\NCreport2\mainwindow.cpp:-1: erreur : undefined reference to `_imp___ZN8NCReportC1EP7QObject'
C:\test\NCreport2\mainwindow.cpp:-1: erreur : undefined reference to `_imp___ZN8NCReport5resetEb'
```

i have checked weather the library is compatible with minGW compiler

i don't get find the symbols in the nm reporot result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766034/free-and-easy-qt-5-1-0-or-qt-4-8-5-reporting-engine/18774024#18774024), you need to talk to your software provider, called NociSoft. Here you can find the website for them:

[Free and easy Qt 5.1.0 or Qt 4.8.5 reporting engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766034/free-and-easy-qt-5-1-0-or-qt-4-8-5-reporting-engine/18774024#18774024)

It is a commercial software, and hence open source volunteers here cannot help further.

Failing that, you can also use eliminate the usage of that symbol from your own application where you use it. There is not much more we can do from this end.

Just talk to your software vendor, and they will be happy to assist. Here you can find their contact availability:

http://www.nocisoft.com/contact.html